# Get class instance from enum type

Tags: java, enums

I have the `Color` enum with:

1. `RED`
2. `BLUE`
3. `GREEN`

I also have these 3 classes:

1. `Red`
2. `Blue`
3. `Green`

My `Testclass` uses the attribute `private Color color` and stores one enum value there. How can I return the corresponding class object when calling `getValue()` or something on `private Color color`?

Example:
If my `Testclass` has `color = Color.RED`, it should return a new instance of the class `Red` when calling `getValue()` on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `enum` a factory.

```
interface AColour {
};

static class Red implements AColour {

}

static class Green implements AColour {

}

static class Blue implements AColour {

}

enum Colour {

    RED {

                @Override
                AColour makeColour() {
                    return new Red();
                }

            },
    GREEN {

                @Override
                AColour makeColour() {
                    return new Green();
                }

            },
    BLUE {

                @Override
                AColour makeColour() {
                    return new Blue();
                }

            };

    abstract AColour makeColour();
}

class TestClass {

    Colour colour = Colour.RED;

    AColour make() {
        return colour.makeColour();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I originally suggested a static map of Color enums to classes but chrylis pointed out in the comments it's simpler just to make it a field and pass it to the constructor.

```
public enum Color {
 RED(Red.class),
 BLUE(Blue.class),
 GREEN(Green.class);

 private Class colorClass;
 public Color(Class classColor)  {
    this.colorClass = classColor;
 }

 public ColorClass getValue() {
     return this.colorClass.newInstance();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is way overkill. Much better to make the `Class` objects a field on the enum type.

Comment: @chrylis Can you explain how you would statically initialize that though? The way I do it avoids needing some sort of setup/initialize method that would need to be called at the right point. I don't see a way to do so, and I think this code is much simpler and more straightforward than the other alternatives. I consider instanceof to be a code smell, and needing to add a new class for every color of the rainbow to also be a code smell. My solution requires one line of additional code when you add a new color. But of course it's all personal preference.

Comment: The "initialize" method is just called the constructor.

Comment: @chrylis Yeah, I thought that's what you were getting at but I forgot you could pass arguments to the constructor when defining the enum. I edited my answer to reflect your suggestion. Also upvoted your comment, I appreciate the code review :)

Answer (score 1):

See [`Class.forName(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)).

> Returns the `Class` object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.

Do not forget to put the full package name of the target.
Then you should declare the `Color` enum like this.

```
public enum Color {
    RED("package.Red"),
    BLUE("package.Blue"),
    GREEN("package.Green");
    private final String value;
    private Color(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

You may need a specific instance, not just a `Class` instance.

```
try {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(Color.RED.getValue());
    if (clazz.isInstance(Red.class)) {
        Red red = (Red)clazz.cast(Red.class);
    } else if (clazz.isInstance(Blue.class)) {
        Blue blue = (Blue)clazz.cast(Blue.class);
    } else if (clazz.isInstance(Green.class)) {
        Green green = (Green)clazz.cast(Green.class);
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFound) {
    // A class named "package.Red" cannot be found
}
```